# Facebook's fql improper ORDER BY sorting

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have this `fql` query:

```
  SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls
    FROM link 
   WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 
                   FROM friend 
                  WHERE uid1 = me()) 
ORDER BY created_time DESC 
   LIMIT 0,200;
```

It's supposed to display last 200 posted links by my friends, but it displays them ordered by `owner` id `ASC` then by `created_time` `DESC`.

Is `ORDER BY` in `fql` limited to one use? How can I make it work?

Comment: Turns out the table _link_ can only be indexed by _link_id_ and _owner_ and discards any other ORDER BY settings. [fql api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `LIMIT` statement. FQL has some odd internal behaviors to optimize their own internal API.

Try removing the `LIMIT` statement and just give it a specific `AND created_time > <point in time>` and see if it orders properly.  If so, that's why.

Comment: I removed the ORDER BY and it didn't change anything. Even specific AND created_time > < does nothing. This must be broken.

Comment: This query had the desired effect:

`select link_id, title, url, owner, owner_comment, created_time, picture from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 50) ORDER BY created_time DESC`

Comment: similar query works for me- `SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, attachment, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 5`